# HttpRequest does not contain a defination for 'GetClientCertificate'( are you missing a using directive or assembly reference) error

Tags: c#, ssl-certificate, asp.net-core-2.1, .net-core-2.1

I am getting below error when using X509Certificate2 class. I have included `using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates`, `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http` Namespaces.

Error is still occurring.. Am I missing something?
Please help!

```
X509Certificate2 cert = Request.GetClientCertificate();
string issuer = cert.Issuer;
string subject = cert.Subject;
```

> HttpRequest does not contain a defination for 'GetClientCertificate'
>   and no accessible extension method 'GetClientCertificate' accepting a
>   first argument of type 'HttpRequest' could be found( are you missing a
>   using directive or assembly reference) error.

I appreciate your help!

Comment: It looks like you are missing an assembly (System.Net.Http)

Comment: Hi user1538301 : I am doing this in .Net core 2.1 I have Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http Namespace too but still I am getting that error.

Comment: Did you try `Request.HttpContext.Connection.ClientCertificate`?

Comment: Thanks Nan Yu. It worked.

Answer (score 2):

This has been answered by [Nan Yu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5751404/nan-yu), the client certificate is available at `Request.HttpContext.Connection.ClientCertificate`.
If you're in an actionFilter, for example, you can use `actionContext.HttpContext.Connection.ClientCertificate`.